# MongoDB TTL + log4mongo

Tags: .net, mongodb

I'm using

```
  <field>
    <name value="timestamp" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date" />
  </field>
```

to store logs with log4mongo, but i'm unable to use that timestamp field for TTL operations.

```
db.logs.ensureIndex( { "timestamp": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

Shouldn't this be possible? If not, what should I do?

P.S. Timestamp is not an indexed field (prior to that ensureIndex call)

Comment: Are you getting an error message back from the ensureindex() call? If so pls add it to your question. Also, can you add an example document from the logs collection (maybe run db.logs.findOne())?

Comment: Is is possible your timestamp is not a native Date type within the MongoDB collection. Possibly your layout is actually producing a string. See the configuration in the [test cases](https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-net/blob/master/src/Log4Mongo.Tests/MongoDBAppenderTest.cs#L39-L42)

Comment: I've submitted a pull request (https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-net/pull/29) to enable TTL indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout was indeed producing a string, correct way to use a timestamp for ensureIndex() is

```
<field>
    <name value='timestamp' />
    <layout type='log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout' />
</field>
```